# Cross-Domain XHR uploading via Javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, file-upload, cross-domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing xml/json response in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866439/parsing-xml-json-response-in-ie9)

I want to implement a Javascript uploader using Imgur API (I think that's the one Stackoverflow uses). However, I haven't been able to make it work. I tried [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) but I got "Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers". Strangely enough, I used [this](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin and I didn't get that error. Instead, I got an XML response saying `<message>No image data was sent to the upload api</message>` (which, I think, was due to the fact that I couldn't send the file object as a parameter called 'image'), as described in the [documentation](https://api.imgur.com/resources_anon):

> image | required | POST | A binary file, base64 data, or a URL

So, my general question is: What is the easiest way to upload to Imgur (considering that they allow Cross-Domain XHR, which is a big advantage) in a cross-browser (IE8+, Chrome, Firefox and friends) way?.

I also read a bit about [HTML5's FormData object](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/), but it seems that even now, cross browser support is not great and I'm not sure if there are javascript implementations for IE8+, Safari, etc.

**UPDATE:** I managed to get this (almost) working using Jquery Form Plugin, but I still have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746515/ie9-refuses-to-process-xml-response) problem (related to IE9). Maybe that's relevant to solve this question, which in turn, would solve the other one.

**UPDATE2:** For future reference, Jquery Form Plugin works fine. However, there is a problem parsing an XML response which contains all the data relevant from Imgur. Please refer to [Parsing xml/json response in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866439/parsing-xml-json-response-in-ie9) to further information about this issue. In short: JSON is not an option, XML should work but it doesn't. You can try server side scripting instead, sending the request via AJAX to a server-side script and letting your script send the upload and receiving the response correctly. In order not to diverge attention from the real issue, I will close this question.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would strongly suggest reading [this](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/04/how-to-upload-arbitrary-file-contents.html)

Answer (score 4):

There's a fully working example for JavaScript in the [Imgur API documentation](http://api.imgur.com/examples#uploading_js).

```
function upload(file) {
   // file is from a <input> tag or from Drag'n Drop
   // Is the file an image?
   if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

   // It is!
   // Let's build a FormData object
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
   fd.append("key", "API_KEY"); // Get your own key: http://api.imgur.com/

   // Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
   xhr.onload = function() {
      // Big win!
      // The URL of the image is:
      JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
   }

   // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
   // And now, we send the formdata
   xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but it's not a cross-browser solution.

Comment: @RobertSmith you didn't specify that as a need in your question.  However, with this you should be able to figure out how to do it in any browser. In which browser do their example not work?

Comment: Actually, it helped a lot. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746515/ie9-refuses-to-process-xml-response.

Comment: By the way, I added a mention to the cross browser requirement.

Comment: I tried this script with java servlet in backend. File is getting uploaded successfully. But I need a success message to display when the AJAX call gets completed. will post a question about this shortly.