# Internet Explorer 8 parse XML doesn`t work on huge response size

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, internet-explorer-8, xml-parsing

I have a huge page with really lots of data. Sometimes I need to reload this data using Ajax, so ajax request:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    this._request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    this._request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Then, I access this data with request.responseXML. I faced a problem, when size of responsibility more than 800k characters. 
IE doesn`t generate responseXML, i`ts just empty XMLObject, but in responseText everithing is OK. I`ve tried to parse XML using the following code:

```
  if (request.responseXML) {
    var responseXML = request.responseXML;

    //TODO: for huge xml responses some versions of IE can't automaticly parse XML
    if (O$.isExplorer && responseXML && !responseXML.firstChild) {
      var originalResponseText = request.responseText;

      if (window.DOMParser) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        responseXML = parser.parseFromString(originalResponseText, 'text/xml');
      } else {            
        responseXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        responseXML.async = false;
        responseXML.loadXML(originalResponseText);
      }
    }
```

But I faced the same problem.
Then, I tried to parse XML using jQuery:

```
responseXML = jQuery.parseXml(request.responseXML);
```

But the problem is still the same, everything is fine when the response length small, but for huge response I still get empty XML object with the parse error inside.

*errorCode : -2147467259*

*filepos : 814853*

*reason : “Unspecified error\r\n”;*

I check those position inside response string and everything is correct, just some ordinal symbol. Also I’ve recheck XML lots of time and I am sure that it’s valid. I don’t know what to do at all.

Also I tried to write my own xml parser, but I think that this is problem has more simple solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that IE notoriously has difficulties parsing XML data, and there may not be that much you can really do about it. A work around is that you can try to parse the XML data with IE, and if it fails, construct a new parser that will construct XML data out of the plaintext (which as you mentioned will work seemingly regardless of size). Take a look at the similar problem and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029902/4889693). It boils down to (pseudocode)

```
function() {
    var XMLdata = reponse.XMLdata;

    If (XMLdata.error) {
        var parser = construct new DOMParser;
        XMLdata = parser.XMLparse(response.plaintext);
    }

    return XMLdata;
}
```